# PHP Array_Combine() Error Combining all elements

Tags: php, arrays

I am attempting to combine two arrays in PHP and using the array combine function, it combines all elements except the last element which seems to be glitching out. I am importing data from a text file. This is the data being imported from the text file:

```
ASN|PO Date|Ship Date|PO Number|Quantity Ordered|Quantity Shipped|Product ID|Unit of Measure|Ship To Name|Ship To Address1|Ship To Address2|Ship To City|Ship To State|Ship To Zip Code|Tracking Number|Carrier|Order Number

ASNData|01/01/17|01/01/2017|1356061|1|1|LEU 171565|EA|ASHLEY DAVIS|15155 23RD AVE N||MINNEAPOLIS|MN|55447|9410811899223445945673|UP39|1234567
```

The goal is to create an associative array with the labels as the keys and the results as the values.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
$content = Storage::disk('billHicksAcknowledgment')->get('856_Advanced_Shipping.txt');
$file = explode("\n", $content);
$labels = $file[0];
$key = explode("|", $labels);
$result = $file[1];
$value = explode("|", $result);
$order = array_combine($key, $value);
print_r($order);
```

When I run the code this is what it echos out into my terminal:

```
Array
(
    [ASN] => ASNData
    [PO Date] => 01/01/17
    [Ship Date] => 01/01/2017
    [PO Number] => 1356061
    [Quantity Ordered] => 1
    [Quantity Shipped] => 1
    [Product ID] => LEU 171565
    [Unit of Measure] => EA
    [Ship To Name] => John Doe
    [Ship To Address1] => 15155 23RD AVE NW
    [Ship To Address2] => 
    [Ship To City] => MINNEAPOLIS
    [Ship To State] => MN
    [Ship To Zip Code] => 55442
    [Tracking Number] => 9410811899223445945673
    [Carrier] => UP39
] => 1234567umber
)
```

If you notice the last element of the array isn't properly printing. When I tried debugging I printed each array separately which returns everything seemingly fine.

Here is the code:

```
$content = Storage::disk('billHicksAcknowledgment')->get('856_Advanced_Shipping.txt');
$file = explode("\n", $content);
$labels = $file[0];
$key = explode("|", $labels);
die(print_r($key)); //code stops and prints first array here
$result = $file[1];
$value = explode("|", $result);
$order = array_combine($key, $value);
print_r($order);
```

Here is the result of that:

```
Array
(
    [0] => ASN
    [1] => PO Date
    [2] => Ship Date
    [3] => PO Number
    [4] => Quantity Ordered
    [5] => Quantity Shipped
    [6] => Product ID
    [7] => Unit of Measure
    [8] => Ship To Name
    [9] => Ship To Address1
    [10] => Ship To Address2
    [11] => Ship To City
    [12] => Ship To State
    [13] => Ship To Zip Code
    [14] => Tracking Number
    [15] => Carrier
    [16] => Order Number
)
1
```

Prints clean right? Now let me print the second array

Here is the code:

```
$content = Storage::disk('billHicksAcknowledgment')->get('856_Advanced_Shipping.txt');
$file = explode("\n", $content);
$labels = $file[0];
$key = explode("|", $labels);
$result = $file[1];
$value = explode("|", $result);
die(print_r($value)); //code stops and prints second array
$order = array_combine($key, $value);
print_r($order);
```

And Here is the result of that:

```
Array
(
    [0] => ASNData
    [1] => 01/01/17
    [2] => 01/01/2017
    [3] => 1356061
    [4] => 1
    [5] => 1
    [6] => LEU 171565
    [7] => EA
    [8] => John Doe
    [9] => 15155 23RD AVE N
    [10] => 
    [11] => MINNEAPOLIS
    [12] => MN
    [13] => 55442
    [14] => 9410811899223445945673
    [15] => UP39
    [16] => 1234567
)
1
```

But when I combine them this is always the result:

```
Array
(
    [ASN] => ASNData
    [PO Date] => 01/01/17
    [Ship Date] => 01/01/2017
    [PO Number] => 1356061
    [Quantity Ordered] => 1
    [Quantity Shipped] => 1
    [Product ID] => LEU 171565
    [Unit of Measure] => EA
    [Ship To Name] => John Doe
    [Ship To Address1] => 15155 23RD AVE NW
    [Ship To Address2] => 
    [Ship To City] => MINNEAPOLIS
    [Ship To State] => MN
    [Ship To Zip Code] => 55447
    [Tracking Number] => 9410811899223445945673
    [Carrier] => UP39
] => 1234567umber
)
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `\r\n` line-endings in your file. Do this:

```
$key = array_map('trim', explode("|", $labels));
...
$value = array_map('trim', explode("|", $result));
```

Comment: Dude you are freaking amazing!! I will accept this answer once it lets me. Thanks again!!